# Overwatered or Underwatered?

Tags: trees

please help !I can't figure it out ... Is this from overwatering or underwatering ?
[image: 3]
[image: 2]
[image: 1]

Comment: Looks more like an infection or something's been spilt on it - what plant is it? Has it  been indoors or outdoors? Anything under the leaves?

Comment: Thanks for replying.So i can't give you the exact answer , becouse i get it from the forest before almost 2 years. It's some kind of European Beech . I grow it on glazed balcony.

Comment: Hi! You were unable to leave this as a comment on your original post because you have a couple of unregistered user accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

If you've had it two years and its a tree sapling, it must surely need a much deeper pot by now to accommodate the deep tap root it wants to put down; as for the browning, its possible that keeping it behind glass might mean the foliage gets scorched when the weather is hot and sunny. Otherwise, its reminiscent of something being spilt or dropped onto the foliage which has damaged it, probably something liquid.